# Custom directive scope in same element as controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controllers

So I have encountered this issue while trying to migrate some working 1.2.16 code to 1.3.0. I've read the release notes, but haven't been able to find out exactly what is causing the issue

What it seems to boil down to is that I am attempting to assign a custom scope via directive to a HTML element that is defined as a controller. This worked fine in the past, and I'm not sure how to get around it.

My directive makes things 'draggable' - it assigns data from my model to the element for native HTML5 drag & drop. My directive:

```
app.directive('draggable', function() {
    return{
        scope: {
            data : '=data'
        },

        link : function(scope, element) {
        // this gives us the native JS object
        var el = element[0];

        el.draggable = true;

        el.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

            e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', JSON.stringify(scope.data));
            this.classList.add('drag');
            return false;
        }, false);

        el.addEventListener('dragend', function(e) {
            this.classList.remove('drag');
            return false;
        }, false);
    }
    }
});
```

How I'm using it:

```
`<div ng:repeat="step in pass.steps" ng:controller="StepEditorController" class="stepcontainer" draggable data="step">`
```

I need the directive to make this whole 'step' element draggable. But now, the custom scope I assign in the directive seems to be giving me trouble. I need the custom scope in order to get that data variable in to define what data is being dragged.

Again, this used to work fine, but now I get a [multidir error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=ngController&p1=draggable&p2=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p3=%3Cdiv%20ng:repeat%3D%22step%20in%20pass.steps%22%20ng:controller%3D%22StepEditorController%22%20class%3D%22stepcontainer%20draggable%22%20draggable%3D%22%22%20data%3D%22step%22%3E) because multiple controllers are attempting to assign scope.

Any hints? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Just a guess, but ng-repeat already creates an isolate scope, so you don't need another isolate scope in your directive. Maybe you can pass the value of the data property with ng-init...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't really need to create an isolate scope, just use the attribute name to find the property on the scope.

In order for your directive to have the same scope as the element in which you define it, remove the scope object from your directive definition (or use scope:true).

Then make sure that you have a reference to the attributes in  your link function

```
link : function(scope, element, attributes) {...}
```

And now instead of using the value on the directive's isolated scope like before, you can just use the property name that you specified in your attribute to access the variable in the scope object

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', JSON.stringify(scope[attributes.data]));
// attributes.data is the name of the property on the scope
```

Here is all of the code together:

```
app.directive('draggable', function() {
    return{
        //scope: { // omit the scope definition so you have the scope of the element itself
        //    data : '=data'
        //},

        link : function(scope, element, attributes) { // you now need to use the attributes
        // this gives us the native JS object
        var el = element[0];

        el.draggable = true;

        el.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

            // take the data from the scope directly using the attribute as the property name
            e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', JSON.stringify(scope[attributes.data])); 
            this.classList.add('drag');
            return false;
        }, false);

        el.addEventListener('dragend', function(e) {
            this.classList.remove('drag');
            return false;
        }, false);
    }
    }
});
```